# how to normalize / update a "order" column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table "mydata" with some data data :

```
id    name       position
===========================
4     foo        -3 
6     bar        -2 
1     baz        -1
3     knork      -1
5     lift       0
2     pitcher    0
```

i fetch the table ordered using `order by position ASC;`

the position column value may be non unique (for some reason not described here :-) and is used to provide a **custom order** during `SELECT`.

what i want to do :

i want to normalize the table column "position" by associating a unique position to each row which doesnt destroy the order. furthermore the highest position after normalising should be -1.

wished resulting table contents :

```
id    name       position
===========================
4     foo        -6 
6     bar        -5 
1     baz        -4
3     knork      -3
5     lift       -2
2     pitcher    -1
```

i tried several ways but failed to implement the **correct** `update` statement.

i guess that using

```
generate_series( -(select count(*) from mydata), -1)
```

is a good starting point to get the new values for the position column but i have no clue how to merge that generated column data into the update statement.

hope somebody can help me out :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
with renumber as (
  select id,
         -1 * row_number() over (order by position desc, id) as rn
  from foo
)
update foo
  set position = r.rn
from renumber r
where foo.id = r.id
  and position <> r.rn;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9edc4/1)

Comment: For performance, add `and position <> r.rn` to the where clause. Else you end up overwriting many rows that shouldn't.

Comment: @Denis: good point. Although I guess it won't probably change very much.

Comment: It can actually be enormous, when most rows contain the correct value (this is frequently the case for ordering indexes). :-) If the entire table is rewritten by the query, it's a good idea to immediately (and manually) vacuum.

Comment: @Denis: it depends I guess. Even if only one row was change all subsequent rows must be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
      id INT
    , name VARCHAR(10)
    , position INT
)

INSERT INTO temp (id, name, position)
VALUES 
    (4, 'foo', -3),
    (6, 'bar', -2),
    (1, 'baz', -1),
    (3, 'knork', -1),
    (5, 'lift', 0),
    (2, 'pitcher', 0)

SELECT 
      id
    , name
    , position = -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position DESC, id) 
FROM temp
ORDER BY position
```

**Update:**

```
UPDATE temp
SET position = t.rn
FROM (
    SELECT id, rn = - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position DESC, id) 
    FROM temp
) t
WHERE temp.id = t.id
```

**Output:**

```
id          name       position
----------- ---------- --------------------
4           foo        -6
6           bar        -5
3           knork      -4
1           baz        -3
5           lift       -2
2           pitcher    -1
```

Comment: The building of the "temp" table will not work with Postgres. Good point in adding the `id` column to the order by of the window function.

Answer (score 1):

@a_horse_with_no_name is really near the truth - thank you !

```
UPDATE temp 
  SET position=t.rn 
  FROM (SELECT 
            id, name, 
            -((select count( *) 
          FROM temp)
            +1-row_number() OVER (ORDER BY position ASC)) as rn
        FROM temp) t 
  WHERE temp.id=t.id;

SELECT * FROM temp ORDER BY position ASC;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d1770/6

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a different result than with my solution. I don't think the `count(*)` is necessary in the sub-select because the highest `row_number()` will automatically be the same as `count(*)`. That's why I used a `DESC` order.

Comment: i have taken your update statement and applied it to different test data and the order is different after the update statement (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/84f5f/6). my solution (derived from yours :-) works well with both test data (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d1770/6).

Answer (score 0):

```
update mydata temp1, (select a.*,@var:=@var-1 sno from mydata a, (select @var:=0) b 
order by position desc, id asc) temp2
set temp1.position = temp2.sno
where temp1.id = temp2.id;
```

Comment: That's not valid SQL for Postgres

Comment: oh sorry I just saw the sql tag and wrote it for mysql

Comment: SQL is *only*  a query language. Based on the tag you can never assume a specific DBMS.

Comment: @chetan That's like folks assuming that "SQL" means "Microsoft SQL Server" :S . Things like `@var` are MySQL extensions.